# Чтобы при (hover) появлялся другой элемент css?

Tags: html, css, hover

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении мыши на кнопку весь сайт накрывался полупрозрачной цветной крышкой, а кнопка оставалась сверху?

Comment: как минимум, хотелось бы увидеть вашу разметку

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.help {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: hotpink;
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
  margin: 10vh auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 10vh;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.help:hover:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -99;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.help:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -99;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<button title="Sweet home" class="help">SWeet </button>
```

Вот так по быстрому

Comment: Если курсор идет вниз, то закрывашка не убирается) Это в примере, а на сайте - она появляется, если навести на кнопку, но не убирается.

Answer (score 5):

Как вариант

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper{}

header,
article,
footer {
  padding: 25px;
}

header {
  background: #ccc;
}

footer {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn{
  position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding: 12px 25px;
  background: tomato;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


.btn + .wrapper:before{
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.btn:hover + .wrapper:before{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">button</button>
<section class="wrapper">
  <header>header</header>
  <article>
    Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное
    животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев
    это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат.
    Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность
    за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую
    ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает
    с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании
    и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности
    при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное!
    
    Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное
    животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев
    это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат.
    Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность
    за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую
    ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает
    с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании
    и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности
    при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное!
    
    Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное
    животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев
    это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат.
    Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность
    за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую
    ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает
    с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании
    и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности
    при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное!
    
    Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное
    животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев
    это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат.
    Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность
    за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую
    ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании и снимает
    с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности при их использовании
    и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное! Все перечисленные на сайте методы ловли льва являются теоретическими и базируются на вычислительных методах. Автор не гарантирует вашей безопасности
    при их использовании и снимает с себя всякую ответственность за результат. Помните, лев это хищник и опасное животное!
  </article>
  <footer>
    footer
  </footer>
</section>
```

Comment: Какой-то странный эффект замутнения на кнопке прослеживается. А так ок.

Comment: @Nikita Smith странный эффект из-за transform: translate(-50%, -50%);